# session variables lost after page redirects in php

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have issues related to the session variables and cookies .Whenever i am submitting the form i loose my session variables in the next redirected I have tried everything `session_start()` at the beginning of each page,and other codes provided in earlier articles .My session is started but then also could not get the session variables in the next page , what i found is that my cookies are not set,is this the problem ? suggest me few ways to set the cookies or get access to my session variables .

Comment: Do you see the `PHPSESSID` cookie on the first request?

Comment: you can easily search how to set cookies on net. lot of articals will going to help you.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at where the session and cookie are set. In the documentation of the cookie http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php you can see `string $path [, string $domain` these are important. as the cookie might be set to a specific directory only

Comment: Make sure that you are not `unsetting` or `destroying`  the session in your first page itself

Comment: Please provide some code snippets. How do you set and get your session vars?

Comment: You're lucky no one's downvoted yet since you haven't provided any code. We can't fix it if we can't see it.

Comment: @Halcyon  i am getting this value for the [PHPSESSID] => 8badbeddb58e2bad80799f32932b31ab and its changing for each computer . The session is setup and for each page infact when i print_r($_SESSION) it shows the value but after submiiting a form  the session variables are  not passed to the next page , and when i print the cookies array it shows a blank array .  I have tried setting the session_save_path() , the path is saved but again the php ini file shows the session path as /tmp ..and the session varaibles cant be acesses ..Need an urgent help

Comment: You don't really need to modify `session_save_path`. Are you messing around with `session_set_cookie_params()`? It's possible that the sessionid-cookie path does not match the form action page. Is there anything special about the form? Is there some XRF protection? (that sometimes uses sessions).

Answer (score 0):

Lets Try to use exit like this every where when you are using redirect.

```
header("Location: /...");
exit();
```

Comment: try to add it in your htaccess php_value session.save_path "/tmp/path/for/save/session"